# How to call an overloaded method from a generic type

Tags: scala

I have this set of overloaded functions:

```
case class A[T](t: T)

object C {
   def dump(a: A[String], s: String) = ....
   def dump(a: A[Int], s: Int) = ....
   def dump(a: A[Double], s: Double) = ....
}
```

and have this generic method:

```
class B {
   def dump[T](a: A[T], t: T) = C.dump(a, t)
}
```

It doesn't compile, because the Scala compiler gets confused with the different overloads.
What is the right way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @drexin answer by using ad-hoc polymorphism, I just slightly change to use the signature of the question to make it a little bit more clear.

`def dump[T](a: A[T], t: T) = C.dump(a, t)`

```
case class A[T](t: T)
trait Dumper[T] {
  def dump(a: A[T], t: T): Unit
}
class B {
  def dump[T](a: A[T], t: T)(implicit dumper: Dumper[T]) = dumper.dump(a, t)
}
implicit val IntDummper = new Dumper[Int] {
  override def dump(a: A[Int], t: Int): Unit = {
    println("int dummper processing it")
  }
}

implicit val StringDummper = new Dumper[String] {
  override def dump(a: A[String], t: String): Unit = {
    println("string dummper processing it")
  }
}

val result = new B

result.dump(A("3"), "3") //string dummper processing it
result.dump(A(3), 3) //int dummper processing it
```

Answer (score 6):

edit: The problem with your implementation is, that at compile time it does not know which version of `C.dump` it should use, because it only know that there is some type `T`, but it can't possibly know what type it will hold when the method is actually being used.

---

You can solve this using ad-hoc polymorphism:

```
trait Dumper[A] {
  def dump(a: A): Unit
}

case class A[T](t: T)

object A {
  implicit object AStringDumper extends Dumper[A[String]] {
    def dump(a: A[String]) = println(s"String: $a")
  }

  implicit object ADoubleDumper extends Dumper[A[Double]] {
    def dump(a: A[Double]) = println(s"Double: $a")
  }
}

object C {
  def dump[A](a: A)(implicit dumper: Dumper[A]) = dumper.dump(a)
}
```

The compiler will try to find an instance of `Dumper[A]` when you call `C.dump`. If it can't find one, it will not compile:

```
scala> C.dump(A("foo"))
String: A(foo)

scala> C.dump(A(1.2))
Double: A(1.2)

scala> C.dump(A(1))
<console>:17: error: could not find implicit value for parameter dumper: Dumper[A[Int]]
              C.dump(A(1))
```

Comment: You mean ad-hoc polymorphism.

Comment: Here is a good explanation of ad-hoc polymorphism: http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/polymorphism.html